# How to get the time difference between two time values stored as strings?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Below is my table fields and its value fields; datatype is varchar.

I want the time difference between the ActualTimeIn and InTime (with hour:minute:second).

```
ActualTimeIn   InTime
09:30:00 AM    1:23:00 PM

09:30:00 AM    11:30:00 AM

09:30:00 AM    11:29:00 AM
```

Expected output is like this:

```
LateComing

3:53:00
2:00:00
1:59:00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @T table(ActualTimeIn time(0), InTime time(0))

insert into @T values
('09:30:00 AM',   '1:23:00 PM'),
('09:30:00 AM',   '11:30:00 AM'),
('09:30:00 AM',   '11:29:00 AM')

select cast(dateadd(s, datediff(s, ActualTimeIn, InTime), 0) as time(0))
from @T
```

Result

```
----------------
03:53:00
02:00:00
01:59:00
```

Comment: @user350104, @nihcap – you can use time(0) as datatype instead.